# Should the option "--rcfile /dev/null" have the same effect as "--norc" when invoking bash?

Tags: bash, arch-linux, shopt

To avoid the XY problem scenario, I'll explain why I'm asking this question.

I remember I had `shopt -s extglob` set in my `~/.bashrc` file, because things like `@(pattern-list)` do work.

However, I've just looked into `~/.bashrc` and that option is not set.

So I decided to see where it comes from, and discovered that

- if I launch another shell via `bash --norc` and then run `shopt` I see the line `extglob off`,
- whereas, if I launch it via `bash --rcfile /dev/null`, then `shopt` shows that `extglob on`,

which doesn't really help me in find out which file is `extglob` is set in.

Based on a comment, `PS4=' $BASH_SOURCE:$LINENO: ' bash -lixc true |& grep extglob` gives

```
   /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion:45: shopt -s extglob progcomp
   /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion:45: shopt -s extglob progcomp
```

Comment: A quick check using `strace -e openat` shows `bash --rcfile /dev/null` opens `/etc/bash.bashrc` in my Ubuntu 18.04, but `bash --norc` doesn't.

Comment: Please post the output of `grep -H extglob ~/.bashrc ~/.profile ~/.bash_profile ~/bash.login ~/.bash_aliases /etc/bash.bashrc /etc/profile /etc/profile.d/* /etc/environment 2> /dev/null`

Comment: @terdon, no output, exist status 2.

Comment: Also try `PS4=' $BASH_SOURCE:$LINENO: ' bash -lixc true |& grep extglob`

Comment: @muru, I've updated the question based on your comment

Comment: As you've discovered, on Arch (and other distros) Bash sources `/etc/bash.bashrc` (based on a compile-time setting). Even when `--rcfile` is specified. This doesn't contradict `man bash` ("`--rcfile file` Execute commands from `file` instead of the standard personal initialization file `~/.bashrc` if the shell is interactive") (it is different on Debian, see the relevant [bug report](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=516152)). This unintuitive behavior has been [reported upstream](https://savannah.gnu.org/support/index.php?107950) as a bug, but the maintainer seems to diagree.

Answer (score 9):

On Debian/Ubuntu, there's also `/etc/bash.bashrc`, which Bash reads similarly to `~/.bashrc`. Using it is a compile time option, and I understand Red Hat does a similar thing by just sourcing a similar file in `/etc/` from the per-user `.bashrc`.

The [Debian documentation](https://manpages.debian.org/buster/bash/bash.1.en.html#OPTIONS) does seem to imply `--rcfile` should override both, as well as `--norc` inhibits reading both:

> `--norc` Do  not  read  and execute the system wide initialization file `/etc/bash.bashrc` and the personal initialization file `~/.bashrc` if the shell is
> interactive.
>
> `--rcfile file`
> Execute  commands  from  file  instead  of  the system wide initialization file `/etc/bash.bashrc` and the standard personal initialization file  `~/.bashrc`

But like @muru said in a comment, that seems wrong, `--rcfile /dev/null` still reads `/etc/bash.bashrc`. So, look there for the `shopt`.

Comment: The only `shopt` is `/etc/bash.bashrc` for me is `[[ $DISPLAY ]] && shopt -s checkwinsize`. By the way, I've update the question specifying I'm on ArchLinux.

Comment: @Enlico, yep. Hard to say what Archlinux does, but their wiki says that "All interactive shells source /etc/bash.bashrc and ~/.bashrc", which does sound similar to the Debian behaviour (that is, the file name is the same). You could check to see if any of those `bashrc` files sources other scripts (`. filename` or `source filename`). Or indeed just `grep -re shopt /etc/` :D

Comment: Yes, Bash is compiled setting `-DSYS_BASHRC` to `/etc/bash.bashrc` on Arch. And `/etc/bash.bashrc` sources `/usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion` if that file exists.